# How to get URL '#' parameter values in PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I am trying to get parameter values from the URL.

```
e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/?id=345#gid=532&sid=567
```

I want to get `gid` and `sid` value from the url, but `$_GET['sid']` and `$_GET['gid']` is not working.

Please help me! How to get these `#` tag values in php?

Answer (score 3):

Th part of an [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) after the `#` is called "fragment" and is by definition only available/processed on client side (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

On the client side, this can be accessed using JavaScript with `window.location.hash`. When you send it to the server somehow, you can use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) function.